# Search Records from zoho creator based on multiselect dropdown in deluge

Tags: zoho

I have two forms "candidates" and "companies" have both having multi-select dropdown "skills_set" .  I want to search the records from the "skills_set" of company and filter records of candidates based on "" using deluge in Zoho creator. Let me know if anyone can help. Here is what I Tried. Java, Php is skillset example but this things not work.

```
responseget = zoho.creator.getRecords("zoomtargen","recruitment-management","All_Candidates","Skills_Set==\"Java,PHP\"");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're coding this inside zoho creator, you could do something like this, consider this for the candidates module:

```
responseget = candidates[Skills_Set = {"Java", "PHP"}];
```

Answer (score 1):

For Internal Integration have some limitation.
Instead of that you can used external API V2. It allowed to much filter.
Ref: https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/v2/get-records.html